# SQL Parameter in Cloudera Impala query

Tags: parameters, pentaho, cloudera, impala

I have a simple question regarding queries running on Impala (I'm using Pentaho report designer as my reporting tool). The query is:

```
select a.*, b.sentatmosphere, b.sentgeneral, b.sentnetcharge, b.sentnetqual, b.sentservice, b.senttidiness 
from p_country_town_hotel a left outer join p_hotel_rev_agg  b on (a.hotel = b.key)  
where a.country = ${Cntry} order by a.City   limit 10000
```

which fails in Pentaho Report designer. The reason is the parameter, because if I change the where clause like: `a.country = 'Denmark'` then I get back results (bullet quick to be precise and that's why we would like to use this). I know that Pentaho want's it's parameters to be written with `${}`, but I haven't found info on Impala using/not using parameters. Any info, ideas, anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to parameterized the HQL with environment variables or hive configuration variables. Can you try...

```
select a.*, b.sentatmosphere, b.sentgeneral, b.sentnetcharge, b.sentnetqual, b.sentservice, b.senttidiness from p_country_town_hotel a left outer join p_hotel_rev_agg b on (a.hotel = b.key)
where a.country = ${env:Cntry} order by a.City limit 10000
```

OR

```
select a.*, b.sentatmosphere, b.sentgeneral, b.sentnetcharge, b.sentnetqual, b.sentservice, b.senttidiness from p_country_town_hotel a left outer join p_hotel_rev_agg b on (a.hotel = b.key)
where a.country = ${hiveconf:Cntry} order by a.City limit 10000
```